# find max in self join after multiple joins

Tags: sql, self-join

i'm trying to find the highest number of interviews from each category (month and city) by joining two different tables and doing a self join in sql

```
`select distinct table1.event_id, table1.month, table1.city

from

(SELECT event_id, count(*) as total_interviews, month, city
FROM company, events
where company.interviewee_id = events.interviewee_id
GROUP BY event_id, month, city) as table1,

(SELECT event_id, count(*) as total_interviews, month, city
FROM company, events
where company.interviewee_id = events.interviewee_id
GROUP BY event_id, month, city) as table2 

WHERE table1.event_id <> table2.event_id
AND table1.month = table2.month
AND table1.city = table2.city`
```

the above code works that shows a self join after multiple join to compare every event_id for the number of total_interviews, but when i add after where

```
AND table1.total_interviews > all (select table2.total_interviews FROM table2 WHERE table2.event_id <> table1.event_id)
```

to find the max value, it gives me an error saying there is no such column for table1 and table2.

the reason why i added this is so that i can determine which event_id has the highest number of interviews compared to the rest, but i haven't been able to find out how to do this

[image: sample data]

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: thanks! just added sample data and the desired output

Comment: could you http://sqlfiddle.com/ it and post a link?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes. PS Your problem is a code extension not returning what you expect. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post.

Comment: table2 in the ALL is not referring to the table value that has alias table2. You can't use a table alias as a table in a subselect FROM. An alias is used with a dot & a column to identify a column in (a representative row of) the result of the join it was introduced in. Give your DBMS & the exact error message. That table2 refers to a base table, and a column from such a table is sought. This means that you need to repeat the tableN subquery. But there are better ways to query for what you want anyway. PS Learn about naming (non-correlated non-lateral) subqueries in CTEs.

Comment: Finding the row based on an aggregate over its group is a faq that even has its own tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. So re your overall goal "find the highest number of interviews from each category": Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS [From the 1st results of my 1st google.](https://stackoverflow.com/q//3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to work back from what I *think* is the source data, before your initial self join, does this give you what you want? This is in sql server.

```
declare @i table(id int, n int, m varchar(30), city varchar(2))
insert @i values (1,4,'Jan','SF')
,(2,5,'Feb','NY')
,(3,6,'Mar','LA')
,(4,3,'Jan','SF')
,(5,2,'Feb','NY')
,(6,1,'Mar','LA')

;with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by m,city order by n desc) roworder 
    from @i
)
select id,m,city from cte 
where roworder=1 
order by id
```

Result is this:

```
id  m   city
1   Jan SF
2   Feb NY
3   Mar LA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use below query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT EventID,total_interviews, Month, City, row_number() over(partition by event_ID,month, City order by total_interviews DESC) as RN
    FROM (
       SELECT Company.event_id, count(*) as total_interviews, Events.month, Events.city, 
       FROM company, events
       where company.interviewee_id = events.interviewee_id
       GROUP BY Company.event_id, Events.month, Events.city 
       ) A
    ) B where RN = 1
```

Comment: this gives me an error: Duplicate colun name "event_id"

Comment: okay. Just indicate what table alias for event ID you need to display. Company.event_ID or Events.Event_ID. same with other columns

Comment: and another error of "unknown column "event_id" in "field list"

Comment: hmm i also tried that, it's still give me the same error

Comment: it says missing from clause entry for table "events" when i write events.event_id

Comment: the error was actually referring to the first select statement

Comment: it works, but the output just gives me all the columns with the number of interviews for each event and NOT the highest number of interviews per event by month/market

Comment: @Eliza apologies I misunderstood your requirement. Please retry using above query.